# Comparing two separate string inputs and finding what they have in common

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am sure there is a better way to describe my problem (hence why I haven't found much on google), but I want to compare two separate strings and pull the substrings they have in common.

Say I have a function that takes two arguments, `"hello,world,pie"` and `"hello,earth,pie"`

I want to return `"hello,pie"`

How could I do this? Here is what I have so far

```
def compare(first, second):
    save = []
    for b, c in set(first.split(',')), set(second.split(',')):
        if b == c:
             save.append(b)




compare("hello,world,pie", "hello,earth,pie")
```

Comment: Use the [intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) of those two sets.

Comment: [Difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

Comment: Have you tried using a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
>>> def common(first, second):
...     return list(set(first.split(',')) & set(second.split(',')))
... 
>>> common("hello,world,pie", "hello,earth,pie")
['hello', 'pie']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "hello,world,pie"
>>> b = "hello,earth,pie"
>>> ','.join(set(a.split(',')).intersection(b.split(',')))
'hello,pie'
```

Comment: downvoter please explain what is wrong. I returned the output string given in the question

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
a="hello,world,pie".split(',')
b="hello,earth,pie".split(',')

print  [i for i in a if i in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

use **set() & set()**:

```
def compare(first, second):
    return ','.join(set(first.split(',')) & set(second.split(','))) 

compare("hello,world,pie", "hello,earth,pie")
'hello,pie'
```